# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception when Build a project by "flutter build appbundle" command

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
>flutter build appbundle
```

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

lib/main.dart:28:20: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.

- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value  = true;
  ^^^^^
  lib/main.dart:29:15: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  user_id.value = userByTokenResponse.id;
  ^^^^^
  lib/main.dart:30:17: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  user_name.value = userByTokenResponse.name;
  ^^^^^
  lib/main.dart:31:18: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  user_email.value = userByTokenResponse.email;
  ^^^^^
  lib/main.dart:32:18: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  user_phone.value = userByTokenResponse.phone;
  ^^^^^
  lib/main.dart:33:23: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'value'.
  avatar_original.value = userByTokenResponse.avatar_original;
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:20:72: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/login",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:28:79: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/social-login",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:39:49: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  "Authorization": "Bearer ${access_token.value}"
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:37:42: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/logout",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:62:73: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/signup",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:73:78: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/resend_code",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:84:79: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/confirm_code",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:96:61: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/password/forget_request",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:111:60: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/password/confirm_reset",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:124:58: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/auth/password/resend_code",
  ^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:132:65: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  var post_body = jsonEncode({"access_token": "${access_token.value}"});
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/auth_repository.dart:135:57: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/get-user-by-access_token",
  ^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:12:32: Error: Method not found: 'FirebaseMessaging'.
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:19:12: Error: The method 'requestNotificationPermissions' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
- 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.
  org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'requestNotificationPermissions'.
  _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:19:43: Error: The method 'IosNotificationSettings' isn't defined for the class 'PushNotificationService'.
- 'PushNotificationService' is from 'package:active_ecommerce_flutter/services/push_notification_service.dart' ('lib/services/push_notification_service.dart'
  ).
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'IosNotificationSettings'.
  _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:26:24: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:33:10: Error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
- 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.
  org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.
  _fcm.configure(
  ^^^^^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:52:34: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == false) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/services/push_notification_service.dart:90:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == false) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/cart.dart:41:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/cart.dart:55:60: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  await CartRepository().getCartResponseList(user_id.value);
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/cart.dart:474:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == false) {

lib/screens/login.dart:99:26: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.

- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/login.dart:131:105: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=$token');
  ^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:17:57: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/profile/counters/${user_id.value}",
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:19:49: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  "Authorization": "Bearer ${access_token.value}"
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:17:64: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/profile/counters/${user_id.value}",
  ^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:28:49: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  var post_body = jsonEncode({"id":"${user_id.value}","name": "${name}", "password": "$password"});
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:31:95: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer ${access_token.value}"},body: post_body );
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:30:76: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/profile/update",
  ^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:40:49: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  var post_body = jsonEncode({"id":"${user_id.value}","device_token": "${device_token}"});`enter code here`

lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:56:95: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.

- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer ${access_token.value}"},body: post_body );
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/profile_repositories.dart:55:82: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/profile/update-image",
  ^
  lib/screens/shipping_info.dart:77:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/shipping_info.dart:83:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/shipping_info.dart:114:38: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  widget.owner_id, user_id.value, _selected_address_city_name);
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/shipping_info.dart:149:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == true) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/screens/shipping_info.dart:643:22: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  if (is_logged_in.value == false) {
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:58:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:62:68: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  AppConfig.BASE_PATH + "${avatar_original.value}",
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:65:48: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  title: Text("${user_name.value}"),
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:67:38: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  user_email.value != "" && user_email.value != null
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:67:64: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  user_email.value != "" && user_email.value != null
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:68:52: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  ? Text("${user_email.value}")
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:69:52: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  : Text("${user_phone.value}"))
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:89:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:106:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:123:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:140:29: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  (is_logged_in.value == true)
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:157:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:175:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == false
  ^^^^^
  lib/ui_sections/drawer.dart:192:28: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  is_logged_in.value == true
  ^^^^^
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/review_repositories.dart:15:73: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  "${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/reviews/product/${product_id}?page=${page}",
  ^
  lib/repositories/review_repositories.dart:31:29: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  "user_id": "${user_id.value}",
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/review_repositories.dart:40:51: Error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.
- 'SharedValue' is from 'package:shared_value/shared_value.dart' ('/C:/android%20development%20tool/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_value-2
  .1.0/lib/shared_value.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.
  "Authorization": "Bearer ${access_token.value}"
  ^^^^^
  lib/repositories/review_repositories.dart:37:59: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  await http.post("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}/reviews/submit",
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\android development tool\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\android development tool\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 37s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       598.1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the first line on your error:

> lib/main.dart:28:20: Error: The setter 'value' isn't defined for the class 'SharedValue'.

Is the problem not that on line 28 you tried to call `SharedValue.value` and it wasn't defined? I've never used the SharedValue package, but from what I could gather, You have to call `SharedValue.$`, so just replace `value` with `$`